Dynamically setting Asset (image) upload path in Data Objects
Using Pimcore 11
I have a Data Object (Product) with a picture (Type:Image) in it. I want to set upload path dynamically based on Product->productCode but I could not find any way to do it.
Using event listeners for preAdd and preUpdate:

I tried setting Product->getPicture()->setUploadPath(..): method undefined
I tried setting Product->getPicture()->setPath(..): no error but no action also

Uploaded images either raise exception (no method) or end up in _default_upload_bucket
I am clearing caches on every bit of change...
